# Nullable Color - assign default value

Tags: c#, interface, xna, nullable, default-value

I have created a small interface `IXnaDraw` for my assets to determine how to draw themselves in XNA. The interface consists of a single method

```
interface IXnaDraw
{
    void Draw(SpriteBatch SB);
}
```

I wanted to pass a `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color`-object along as I have a change of context and this needs a different color-scheme to be applied to the assets.

I tried to use a `nullable` Color-object like in

```
void Draw(SpriteBatch SB, Color? Col = null);
```

The default-parameter is not accepted, I get the error that my classes do not implement said interface. I also tried to use things like

```
void Draw(SpriteBatch SB, Color Col = Color.White);
```

this invokes an error stating

> The value must be known at compile-time.

How can I fix the implementation and have my default-parameter? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the 4.0 or higher .NET

```
void Draw(SpriteBatch SB, Color Col = default(Color));
```

or

```
void Draw(SpriteBatch SB, [Optional]Color Col);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Though it took a minute to figure `Optional` to be `System.Runtime.Interop.OptionalAttribute` it is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accept a second parameter, you need to create a second overload of the method that takes two parameters.
Interface implementations must match exactly; the CLR does not recognize optional parameters.

You can make the single-parameter version call the other overload, if you want to.